# Binding to fe80::%<scope>

Tags: c, macos, posix, ipv6

Trying to get daemon to bind to `fe80::%en0`.

I'm not 100% sure this is possible, but it really seems like for the link-local address to be useful it should be.

If you want to accept packets from  your peer on the other side of the link, it seems stupid to have to specify the full link-local address.

The code looks like this:

```c
if (DEBUG_ENABLED4) {
    if (salocal.ss_family == AF_INET) {
        char            buffer[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        struct sockaddr_in  *addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)&salocal;

        inet_ntop(addr->sin_family, &addr->sin_addr, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        DEBUG4("[FD %i] Binding to address %s port %u -- bind(%i, %p, %u)",
               this->fd, buffer, ntohs(addr->sin_port), this->fd, &salocal, salen);
    } else if (salocal.ss_family == AF_INET6) {
        char            buffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        struct sockaddr_in6 *addr = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&salocal;

        inet_ntop(addr->sin6_family, &addr->sin6_addr, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        DEBUG4("[FD %i] Binding to address %s port %u scope ID %i -- bind(%i, %p, %u)",
               this->fd, buffer, ntohs(addr->sin6_port), addr->sin6_scope_id,
               this->fd, &salocal, salen);
    }
}
rad_suid_up();
rcode = bind(this->fd, (struct sockaddr *)&salocal, salen);
rad_suid_down();
```

The debug output looks like this:

```
Sat Nov  7 19:58:28 2015 : Debug: [FD 12] Binding to address fe80:: port 1812 scope ID 4 -- bind(12, 0x7fff599dc4d0, 28)
Sat Nov  7 19:58:28 2015 : Error: Failed binding to auth address fe80:: port 1812 bound to server default: EADDRNOTAVAIL: Can't assign requested address
Sat Nov  7 19:58:28 2015 : Error: /usr/local/freeradius/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[215]: Error binding to port for fe80:: port 1812
```

Ifconfig output looks like this:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether a8:20:66:xx:xx:xx 
    inet6 fe80::aa20:66ff:fe1a:8bcd%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
```

Values all seem to match up, but bind returns `EADDRNOTAVAIL`.  Is there some magic socket option I need to enable to make this work? Or do I need to check for that link local IP prefix specifically and then resolve it to the full address for the interface described by the scope_id/zone_id?

Comment: Can't you just bind to the unspecified address?

Comment: As in ``::`` sure, but it's not equivalent.

Comment: Please explain why it is different in your context. Normally, you want to bind to the unspecified address for listening.

Comment: Well, no, you'd bind to the unspecified address to bind that particular port on every interface.  I want to receive datagrams only from link-local peers.  Binding to in6addr_any would mean i'd receive datagrams on interfaces with other scopes as well.

Comment: Do you normally bind to a subnet address rather than an address configured on your host?

Comment: No, but randomisation of link-local addresses would make specifying the full address fragile.  It'd be useful in those cases to allow binding specifically to the link-local scoped address of an interface, without specifying the actual address.

As other addresses INADDR_ANY/in6addr_any trigger special bind() behaviour, it seemed probable that there might exist a 'bind to link-local scoped addresses' address or failing that a socket option.

Comment: If you want to restrict incoming traffic to the local link, you can subscribe to a link local multicast address; there are an almost uncountable number of them in IPv6.

Comment: Yes, that would work.  It still requires the user to have knowledge of the multicast address though, instead of just being able to use ``fe80::<scope>`` (which does work) to establish the connection.

Comment: `inet_ntop` drops the scope, stick to `getaddrinfo` and `getnameinfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: if you want to bind to a specific address you'll have to specify that address. A host can have multiple link-local addresses. If you want to bind to all link-local addresses automatically you'll have to auto-discover them and create a socket for each of them.

Comment: Can a host have multiple link-local addresses per interface?

Comment: Yes, multiple link-local addresses isn't very common but certainly not unheard of.

Comment: What the main use case for them?

Comment: I mostly see them as a default gateway, for example in a datacenter where on each LAN the address `fe80::1` is usable as a default gateway, besides the link-local addresses of the routers. One reason for this was that certain Cisco IOS releases could only do HSRP with link-local addresses.